# unable to write for loop in javascript and unable to upload data to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to create an online examination page for students. Questions are meant to be loaded into javascript and after clicking a button the answers need to be uploaded to a MySQL database.

Unable to find the error, please help me.

```
<style>
div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:10px 40px 40px 40px; }
</style>
<script>
var res = <?= $r?>;
var no =<?= $n?>;
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
                for(var a=0; a<=4; a++){
        [ "<?= $r[1]?>", "<?= $r[5]?>", "<?= $r[6]?>", "<?= $r[7]?>", "<?= $r[8]?>", "<?= $r[9]?>"]
                }
    ];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][1];
    chA = questions[pos][2];
    chB = questions[pos][3];
    chC = questions[pos][4];
    chD = questions[pos][5];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chD+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
```

Comment: "*Unable to find the error*"? Exactly **what** error are you having? Is there no output? Does anything show in your console? There are numerous 'problems'. You set `test` as `_("test");` rather than a DOM node, and you never actually insert it to the page.

Comment: no output displayed on webpage. but when i inspect webpage i can see php variable values in code. i think for loop error is in for loop.                              for(var a=0; a<=4; a++){
        [ "<?= $r[1]?>", "<?= $r[5]?>", "<?= $r[6]?>", "<?= $r[7]?>", "<?= $r[8]?>", "<?= $r[9]?>"]
                }
    ];

Comment: please edit your own question to add in the details on the actual error you are facing.

Comment: `[ "<?= $r[1]?>", "<?= $r[5]?>", "<?= $r[6]?>", "<?= $r[7]?>", "<?= $r[8]?>", "<?= $r[9]?>"]`. I predict this will produce a syntax error in JS. Did you check your browser console for errors? It will just output 4 arrays (the same one, repeated 4 times), but without declaring any variable to hold them, or any semicolons between them. This is so garbled I can't even be sure what you're trying to achieve with this code. `a` is declared but never used except as a counter, and then you just repeat the same output from PHP 4 times. Is this supposed to contain your question data?